# Use static C library with Swift package manager

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I'd like to use the Swift package manager to include a *static* C library in my build. [Apple's documentation](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/swift-3.0-preview-1-branch/Documentation/SystemModules.md) shows the process with shared libraries but I'm hoping there's a way to use static. I am able to link against static libraries using `swiftc`, so it seems reasonable to hope that I should be able to do so using `swift build`.

I have a small example problem which uses a static C library containing a function for multiplying two numbers together. (Note: I'm running Swift 3 Preview 1 on Linux)

The directory structure that looks like this:

```
example/
    Package.swift
    main.swift
    .git/

CMult/
    Package.swift
    module.modulemap
    mult.h
    libmult.a
    .git/
```

Contents of example/Package.swift:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "example",
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "../CMult", majorVersion: 1)
    ]
)
```

Contents of example/main.swift:

```
import CMult

let n: Int32 = mult2(3, 5) // "int mult2(int,int)" is in mult.h and libmult.a
print("Result = \(n)")
```

Contents of CMult/Package.swift:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "CMult"
)
```

Contents of CMult/module.modulemap:

```
module CMult [system] {
    header "./mult.h"
    link "mult"
    export *
}
```

Now the problem is when I run `example$ swift build`, the linker complains with the error, "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmult", which isn't surprising since it's not there and I haven't told it where else to look. What I'd like is some way to specify the -L flag in the module map, specifying where to look for the .a file (this is how I linked against my .a with `swiftc`). A less desirable but acceptable solution seemed to be to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to look in CMult/ but that didn't change the error.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to specify library locations in a module map, but here is what worked for me:

```
example$ swift build -Xlinker -L../CMult
```

You can find some other useful options by running

```
swift build --help
```

As for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, that's for searching shared libraries.  For static it would be `LIBRARY_PATH`, but that one didn't work with `swift build` when I tried it.  It does work with `gcc`, though.